# Use awk to remove scientific notation in a column

Tags: awk, scientific-notation

While I'm sure that this has been answered *somewhere*, I can't find where, so I'm very sorry if this is a repeat. Here we go.

I have a file (really, I have many files) that has X, Y, and Z data points separated by spaces into three columns. I'm trying to 3d plot these with GNUplot, which, sadly, doesn't seem very pleased with scientific notation. Now, I can **sed** my way to (A*10**B) notation instead of (AE+B) notation, but GNUplot still doesn't recognize it.

I know I can convert from scientific notation with printf "%.5f" (I think five digits would be just fine), but I can't find how to format my input so that I can apply this to multiple columns, or, better yet, how to control the format for each column. I can convert a single value:

```
echo ""|awk '{printf "%.5f", $2}' k11edit.dat
```

but I can't get it to handle multiple columns, nor even to maintain a space between values (a tab would be just fine, too; I'm not partial to a single space).

Here are a couple lines of my file:

```
0.995 8.1584E-004 -0.17051415E+01
0.995 8.8934E-004 -0.17053282E+01
0.995 9.6284E-004 -0.17055150E+01
0.995 1.0363E-003 -0.17057018E+01
0.995 1.1098E-003 -0.17058886E+01
0.995 1.1833E-003 -0.17060754E+01
0.995 1.2568E-003 -0.17062623E+01
0.995 1.3303E-003 -0.17064493E+01
0.995 1.4038E-003 -0.17066362E+01
0.995 1.4773E-003 -0.17068232E+01
0.995 1.5508E-003 -0.17070103E+01
0.995 1.6243E-003 -0.17071973E+01
0.995 1.6978E-003 -0.17073846E+01
```

Yes, I'm aware that the first column doesn't change in these few lines, but it does further down (the file is ~30,000 lines long, so I thought a few lines would suffice here).

Could you help me out?

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that sample input as it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: My gnuplot (version 4.6) has no problem with this notation: `splot 'k11edit.dat' u 1:2:3 w lp` shows your data points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your expected output it's a guess but is this what you want:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%.5f%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
0.99500 0.00082 -1.70514
0.99500 0.00089 -1.70533
0.99500 0.00096 -1.70551
0.99500 0.00104 -1.70570
0.99500 0.00111 -1.70589
0.99500 0.00118 -1.70608
0.99500 0.00126 -1.70626
0.99500 0.00133 -1.70645
0.99500 0.00140 -1.70664
0.99500 0.00148 -1.70682
0.99500 0.00155 -1.70701
0.99500 0.00162 -1.70720
0.99500 0.00170 -1.70738
```

If you want a different format for each field:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("%.3f %.7f %.4f",fmt)}
       {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf fmt[i]"%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
0.995 0.0008158 -1.7051
0.995 0.0008893 -1.7053
0.995 0.0009628 -1.7055
0.995 0.0010363 -1.7057
0.995 0.0011098 -1.7059
0.995 0.0011833 -1.7061
0.995 0.0012568 -1.7063
0.995 0.0013303 -1.7064
0.995 0.0014038 -1.7066
0.995 0.0014773 -1.7068
0.995 0.0015508 -1.7070
0.995 0.0016243 -1.7072
0.995 0.0016978 -1.7074
```

Comment: I loved your use of `?:` to spell out the delimiter enough to explain your code.  Since it is _your_ answer and not mine, I didn't otherwise comment.  The second form could be written without neither a `BEGIN` stanza nor a loop as: `awk '{printf "%.3f%s%7f%s%.4f%s", $1, OFS, $2, OFS, $3, ORS}'`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AdamKatz yes, I made it more general than necessary for this specific question so when others look it up in future and they don't have 3 fixed fields they can see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky way of doing it using `OFMT` and forcing conversion to string.

```
$ awk -v OFMT='%.5f' '{print $1+"",$2+"",$3+""}' file

0.99500 0.00082 -1.70514
0.99500 0.00089 -1.70533
0.99500 0.00096 -1.70551
0.99500 0.00104 -1.70570
0.99500 0.00111 -1.70589
0.99500 0.00118 -1.70608
0.99500 0.00126 -1.70626
0.99500 0.00133 -1.70645
0.99500 0.00140 -1.70664
0.99500 0.00148 -1.70682
0.99500 0.00155 -1.70701
0.99500 0.00162 -1.70720
0.99500 0.00170 -1.70738
```

however, it doesn't convert if the number is an integer.

Comment: It will convert values to numbers if you use `$1 / 1` rather than `$1  + ""`

Comment: Yes, but need to convert numbers to strings to use the OFMT.  Regardless, it's a hack and printf should be the preferred way.

Comment: Integers won't work either way.  You'd have to do `a=0.000001; print $1+a,$2+a,$3+a` to work around that (`a` is `⅒⁽ⁿ⁺¹⁾` where `ⁿ` is the desired precision), and that would make values like 0.000004 erroneously round up.

Comment: this's not a good hack for ints.  You can do`$1+($1==int($1)?eps:0)` instead.